# Unable to locate VLC package in my repositories?

Tags: apt

When I try to install VLC using apt-get, I get the following error:

```
parameswaran@parameswaran-Compaq-Presario-CQ61-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc
[sudo] password for parameswaran: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc
```

It's happening in my Ubuntu i386 Compaq Presario cq61, and I'm new Ubuntu user.

Somebody please tell me how to solve this issue and install packages in my laptop?

Comment: Why are you trying to install on a terminal when VLC is listed within the **Ubuntu software center** for download??

Comment: Try updating and upgrading your computer first. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: @AzkerMohamed it could be that he doesn't use/like the USC (like me).

Comment: @AzkerMohamed Counterpoint: Why should he have to use the Ubuntu Software Center when VLC is listed as a package in the universe repository? Either is a perfectly valid option.

Answer (score 2):

vlc is in universe repository. Most probably that's not enabled. You can either go to software center to add it run

```
 sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
```

(copied from [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository))

After that, run

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: In those cases you might prefer `sudo add-apt-repository http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ universe`

Comment: @Braiam good point, fixed that. At least on 12.04 you have to specify full url of repository for `add-apt-repository`.

Answer (score -2):

Open up the terminal and run `software-properties-gtk`, change server to main server
then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This may answer the question, however you could improve the answer by posting why this will work, as well as improve readability.